# Dúvida com SELECT e SUB SELECT em MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a SQL, nunca trabalhei com sub selects e acabei ficando perdido com ele.

**Meu SQL:**

```
SELECT CLI.id, CLI.nome, CLI.senha, CLI.email, CLI.cpf, CLI.celular, CLI.data_nasc, CLI.genero, CLI.data_cadastro, CLI.status, CLI.id_socket, ATEN.mensagem, ARQ.nome AS foto, ATEN.data_mensagem
FROM ut_clientes AS CLI
LEFT JOIN ut_arquivos AS ARQ ON (ARQ.id_tipo = CLI.id AND ARQ.tipo = "ut_clientes")
INNER JOIN ut_atendimentos AS ATEN ON (ATEN.id_usuario_envio = CLI.id)
WHERE ATEN.id_usuario_envio != 1
GROUP BY CLI.id 
ORDER BY ATEN.data_mensagem
DESC
```

Bom, o que eu gostaria de fazer era agrupar as mensagens de acordo com o ID do cliente e trazer apenas a ultima mensagem gravada no banco de acordo com a data_mensagem.

Já tentei de várias formas mas sempre a ultima que é exibida é a primeira mensagem inserida no banco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a cláusula `EXISTS` em conjunto com o `NOT` para selecionar apenas a mensagem com a data maior:

```
SELECT cli.id,
       cli.nome,
       cli.senha,
       cli.email,
       cli.cpf,
       cli.celular,
       cli.data_nasc,
       cli.genero,
       cli.data_cadastro,
       cli.status,
       cli.id_socket,
       aten.mensagem,
       arq.nome AS foto,
       aten.data_mensagem
  FROM ut_clientes AS cli
       LEFT JOIN ut_arquivos AS arq ON arq.id_tipo = cli.id
                                   AND arq.tipo = "UT_CLIENTES"
       LEFT JOIN ut_atendimentos AS aten ON aten.id_usuario_envio = cli.id
 WHERE aten.id_usuario_envio <> 1
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM ut_atendimentos AS aten2
                   WHERE aten2.id_usuario_envio = cli.id
                     AND aten2.data_mensagem > aten.data_mensagem)
 GROUP BY cli.id
 ORDER BY aten.data_mensagem DESC
```

> [**Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> If a subquery returns any rows at all, `EXISTS` subquery is `TRUE`, and `NOT EXISTS` subquery is `FALSE`.

Ou em tradução livre:

> Se a subquery retornar qualquer linha, `EXISTS` será `VERDADEIRO`, e `NOT EXISTS` será `FALSO`.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, muito obrigado!

Comment: @TiagoPaza não esqueça de marcar a resposta como escolhida caso tenha atendido a sua pergunta

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT CLI.id, CLI.nome, CLI.senha, CLI.email, CLI.cpf, CLI.celular, CLI.data_nasc, CLI.genero, CLI.data_cadastro, CLI.status, CLI.id_socket, ATEN.mensagem, ARQ.nome AS foto, ATEN.data_mensagem
FROM ut_clientes AS CLI
LEFT JOIN ut_arquivos AS ARQ ON (ARQ.id_tipo = CLI.id AND ARQ.tipo = "ut_clientes")
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a.data_mensagem, a.mensagem
    FROM ut_atendimentos a
    WHERE a.id_usuario_envio = CLI.id
    ORDER BY a.data_mensagem DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS ATEN
WHERE ATEN.id_usuario_envio != 1
GROUP BY CLI.id;
```